# Cross-datacenter sync after failure

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra

could anyone explain me what happens in these scenarios, in particular why in the 2nd one the data is never synchronized.

Intro:

- 2 DCs, keyspace with NetworkTopologyStrategy {DC-1 : 3, DC-2: 3}
- all writes and reads are with CL = LOCAL_QUORUM
- 'write x to dc-2' means that i use cqlsh to connect to some cassandra instance in DC-2 and perform some write operation.
- 'dc-1 dies' means that all cassandra instances have been terminated (kubectl delete pod)

---

Scenario 1 - which I understand

1. DC-1 dies.
2. Write x to DC-2
3. DC-1 comes back to life
4. Read on DC-1 gives back correct result after a couple seconds

That's the wanted behaviour - data is eventually in sync

---

Scenario 2

1. DC-1 dies.
2. Write x to DC-2
3. DC-2 dies
4. DC-1 comes back to life
5. Read on DC-1 gives back stale data
6. DC-2 comes back to life
7. Read on DC-1 gives back stale data after long period of time

In this scenario, is the data going to be in sync throughout the DC's ever again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both scenario you need to run nodetool repair on each node on both DCs. however cassandra nodes store hints for specific time which is default 3 hrs. Repair ensures consistency of data on cassandra cluster.